# Libre office configuration file bootstrap.ini corrupt

Tags: libreoffice

I am using the [libreoffice-convert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/libreoffice-convert) package to convert a Word file into PDF. But when I try to convert I get this error. How do I fix this? I have installed LibreOffice 7.0.5

[image]

Console log is showing this error:

```
'C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice\\program\\soffice.exe -env:UserInstallation=file://C:\\Users\\thesa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\soffice-10416-bQefydwUfs2F --headless --convert-to .pdf --outdir C:\\Users\\thesa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libreofficeConvert_-10416-v46bO7ljGHRe C:\\Users\\thesa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\libreofficeConvert_-10416-v46bO7ljGHRe\\source'
```

Comment: As an unrelated note, what you posted is not an error but the command line to let LibreOffice do the conversion. Would you mind to show the surrounding? -- Did you try to run this "by hand" with some "real" paths? The used ones look like temporary paths and files.

Answer (score 1):

`-env:UserInstallation` needs to be in URI form.

**Note:** also that you using `file://` this should be `file:///` see [File URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

```
-env:UserInstallation=file:///C:/Users/thesa/AppData/Local/Temp/soffice-10416-bQefydwUfs2F
```

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path

>>> def get_posix(mypath) -> str:
>>>     p = Path(mypath)
>>>     return p.as_posix()

>>> tmp = "C:\\Users\\thesa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\soffice-10416-bQefydwUfs2F"

>>> get_posix(tmp)
'C:/Users/thesa/AppData/Local/Temp/soffice-10416-bQefydwUfs2F'
```

or

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path

>>> tmp = Path("C:\\Users\\thesa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\soffice-10416-bQefydwUfs2F")
>>> tmp.as_uri()
'file:///C:/Users/thesa/AppData/Local/Temp/soffice-10416-bQefydwUfs2F'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you will probably need administrator rights.

1. Locate and copy your orignal file, for example to "bootstrap.ini.org", in the same directory<sup>1</sup>.
2. Open the file and replace its contents with this, which is a copy of my file:

   ```
   [Bootstrap]
   InstallMode=<installmode>
   ProductKey=LibreOffice 7.0
   UserInstallation=$SYSUSERCONFIG/LibreOffice/4
   ```

Another option is to re-install or repair the installation.

Note 1: This copy is just in case you need to revert.

Comment: Tried this but still the same error is showing.

Comment: OK. Did you try to re-install or repair?

Comment: Did you find a workaround? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
//let data = await fs.promises.readFile(path_to_excel_file);
            let data = fs.readFileSync(path_to_excel_file)
            let pdfFile = await libreConvert(data, '.pdf', undefined);
            await fs.promises.writeFile(`${__dirname}/${docName}.pdf`, pdfFile);
            res.download(`${__dirname}/${docName}.pdf`)
```

It will works File.
Even If don't work then follow
below step:
Add this line 14 after instalDir

```
const installDir = tmp.dirSync({prefix: 'soffice', unsafeCleanup: true, ...tmpOptions});
const posixInstallDir = installDir.name.split(path.sep).join(path.posix.sep);
```

then Replace commant

```
let command = `${results.soffice}  --headless --convert-to ${format}`;
```

That's it..